# Scrolling a child div dynamically when the parent has max-height

Tags: html, css

I have a side panel that should be exactly the height of its content, up to some maximum height. Inside is a gallery of components which should scroll if it overflows. I can't get it to scroll with `max-height` on the parent container. If I set a some value on the `height` property, it scrolls, but then it doesn't shrink with its content.

Here's a repro of the problem, with the left container being an example of the case that should scroll, and the right container being an example of the case that shrinks to fit the content:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent-container {
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 500px;
}

.flex-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.scrolling-container {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div>
      This box should hit the max height and start scrolling the inner div
    </div>
    <div class="scrolling-container">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div>This div stays on bottom</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent-container">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div>
      This container shouldn't scroll and should only be as tall as the content
    </div>
    <div class="scrolling-container">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div>This div stays on bottom</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you throw `height: 500px` on `parent-container`, you can see the scrolling behavior that I'm going for.

Is there any way to do this with just CSS, or do I need to use JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `max-height` property needs to be applied to the container you want to scroll.  In order to keep it consistent to the ancestor's max-height, you can put `max-height: inherit` on all the child containers that are ancestors of the scrolling container.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent-container {
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 500px;
}

.flex-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: inherit;
}

.scrolling-container {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height:inherit;
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div>
      This box should hit the max height and start scrolling the inner div
    </div>
    <div class="scrolling-container">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div>This div stays on bottom</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent-container">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div>
      This container shouldn't scroll and should only be as tall as the content
    </div>
    <div class="scrolling-container">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div>This div stays on bottom</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Accepting this answer because it did solve my minimum repro, but my actual use case is a little more complicated and it only moved the problem there. Definitely helps with tracking it down, though.

Comment: If you are able to provide a minimum repro of the new problem and create a new question, I'm happy to take a look.  Or if you can link a codepen or similar I can look at that as well.

Answer (score 1):

PsiKai's answer is awesome.  I wanted to offer an alternative that requires less wrappers too.  This approach uses `grid` and `min-content`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.parent-container {
  width: 20rem;
  border: 1px solid;
  max-height: 20rem;
  
  /* 
    grid with 3 rows
    header and footer rows will 
    have height of their content
    scroll-container will grow
    to fill the remainder
  */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr min-content;
}

.scrolling-container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  
  /*
    could be flex here, but then
    you have to set the direction
    and the items may need flex 
    setting adjustments
  */
  display: grid;
  gap: .5rem;
}

.item {
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: red;
}

header, 
footer {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<section class="parent-container">
    <header>
      This parent-container hits the max height of 500px and starts scrolling the scrolling-container
    </header>
    <div class="scrolling-container">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <footer>This div stays on bottom</footer>
</section>
```

: